# Disk usage on a specific filesystem

Tags: filesystems, mount, disk-usage

I need to find out what's contributing to the disk usage on a specific filesystem (`/dev/sda2`):

```
$ df -h /
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda2              96G   82G  9.9G  90% /
```

I can't just do `du -csh /` because I have many other filesystems mounted underneath `/`, some of which are huge and slow:

```
$ df -h
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda2              96G   82G  9.9G  90% /
/dev/sdb1             5.2T  3.7T  1.3T  76% /disk3
/dev/sda1              99M   18M   76M  20% /boot
tmpfs                  16G  4.0K   16G   1% /dev/shm
nfshome.XXX.net:/home/userA
                      5.3T  1.6T  3.5T  32% /home/userA
nfshome.XXX.net:/home/userB
                      5.3T  1.6T  3.5T  32% /home/userB
```

How can I retrieve disk usage **only** on `/dev/sda2`?

None of these work:

- Attempt 1:

  ```
  $ du -csh /dev/sda2
  0       /dev/sda2
  0       total
  ```
- Attempt 2:

  ```
  $ cd /dev/sda2/
  cd: not a directory: /dev/sda2/
  ```

Comment: Maybe I am missing something, but why doesn't the `Used` column give you what you are looking for?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Use the `-x` (single file system) option:

```
du -cshx /
```

This instructs `du` to only consider directories of `/` which are on the same file system.

Comment: Thanks Stephen. Not sure this works the way I understand it does (see [this followup](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/358323/du-results-on-filesystem-inconsistent-with-df))

Comment: Note that the magic here is the `-x` option. The other options here, mirroring the OP approach, report in human-readable numbers, and summarize the results, including a grand total. So for example, `du -x /` would give a full description of all files on the root file system.

Comment: The problème is that one would normally do `du -x /*` - to see what directory is using the most of the space of the root partition. How to exclude from this result the directories that are on a different filesystem?

Comment: @Andrei if you’re using GNU `du`, `du -x --max-depth=1 /`.

Answer (score 1):

There are two options to solving your problem:

Using the option `--exclude` which makes `du` ignore the given path.

```
du --human-readable --exclude=/home
```

Using the option `--one-file-system` would tell `du` to not go into a different file system.

```
du --human-readable --one-file-system /
```

Comment: I have home on a different partition but when I use `du -hd1x \` the home directory is included. I use debian stretch. What do I misunderstand in "one file system"?

Comment: To find directories containing a large size, I would recommend adding `--max-depth=1`: `du --human-readable --one-file-system --max-depth=1`

Answer (score 0):

On some Linux distro you could take advantage of `ncdu`.

To check your HOME folder:

```
$ ncdu ~
```