# du results on filesystem inconsistent with df

Tags: command-line, filesystems, mount, disk-usage

What explains the discrepancy in usage (`82 GB` vs `13 GB`) that I see below?

- Using `df`:

  ```
  $ df -h /
  Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
  /dev/sda2              96G   82G  9.9G  90% /
  ```
- Using `du`:

  ```
  $ sudo du -cshx /
  13G     /
  13G     total
  ```

Comment: Maybe you have 69 gigs of data in a subdirectory that got mounted over where `du` can't see it?

Comment: Might be because of files that were deleted but are still kept open by some process; you should try `lsof +L1`.

Comment: Relevant: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/120311/why-are-there-so-many-different-ways-to-measure-disk-usage

Comment: If the filesystem is [btrfs](https://btrfs.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/FAQ#Help.21_Btrfs_claims_I.27m_out_of_space.2C_but_it_looks_like_I_should_have_lots_left.21) things can get messy.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`-x` option is a false friend as its purpose is to skip things. That option never gives you the complete picture.

To get a complete listing, use bind mounts and then `du`, `ncdu`, `xdiskusage`, `baobab` or whatever you wish on the bound directory without skip options:

```
mkdir /mnt/root
mount --bind / /mnt/root
ncdu /mnt/root
```

Then you might discover you have lots of stuff in `/mnt/backup` (because it wasn't mounted when the backup task ran), or a giant file in `/dev` (result of a `dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdx` when no `/dev/sdx` existed and no tmpfs was mounted in `/dev`).

It could also be a deleted file still used by a process, but people don't usually ask about it as it's gone after reboot. It could also be a filesystem inconsistency, but that too would be gone after reboot (if it forces `fsck` in the process).

Comment: Thanks! Rebooting the machine did it +1. Interesting that `du` "loses" track of space until I restarted the machine

Comment: @AmelioVazquez-Reina The usual reason is that there's a large deleted file that some process still has open. The file contents don't go away until the process closes it, but `du` can't count it because it just traverses the directory.