# How to know what consumes storage?

Tags: centos, disk-usage

I have a Centos 7 VM and I want to know what consumes the 126G on the 
**/dev/mapper/centos-root** fs. I have 2 mount points and I unmounted them to make sure there's nothing reserving space under them and mounted them again .

[image]

I've also ran `sudo lsof +aL1` but there was nothing reserving GBs

Is there more efficient way to know what consumes space ?

Comment: For the future, please do not post screenshots but copy output from terminal to your question. If you want to know what consumes space you can use `du` command

Comment: Looking at the completely empty /home, probably it's in the /home of the / filesystem. umount /home or bind-mount / to find out...

Comment: see also https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/358331/30851

Comment: I use this script to find the largest directories: `find / -mount -print0|xargs -0 -P 4 --max-lines 1 du -sb|sort -n -r >sizes.txt`. The result will be in `sizes.txt` of your current directory.

Comment: thanks all for your replies ,@peterh this command gives me xargs: 1: No such file or directory

Comment: @frostschutz /home is almost empty I believe the issue isn't there

Comment: @Mawardy if you can rule out hidden or deleted-but-still-open files, try forcing a filesystem check.

Comment: @frostschutz sorry for my late reply , i've used lsof for that and i've noticed there'r  2x "67108864 byte" deleted files related to pulseaudio , I've killed the two processes but they come again automatically , don't know if that's the reason

Answer (score 1):

Run this command (as root) to find the 10 largest directories:

```
du -a / | sort -n -r | head
```

Comment: I've unmounted all mount points and ran this command as root it showed that /var was the biggest directory with about 41Gigs nothing else was showed up but the /var directory and it's sub directories , i've also ran ncdu and the same output was presented , df still shows 126G

Comment: Check `/var/log`, logfiles are the usual culprit.

Comment: not too much there , only 82904 bytes