# Purpose of cp -x (stay on file system)?

Tags: command-line, files, filesystems, cp, data

If I wanted to stay on the same file system, couldn't I just specify an output path for the same file system?

Or is it to prevent accidentally leaving the current file system?

Comment: -x in a different context: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/358331/30851 but same for cp: -x skips things, if you are migrating filesystems and would like it to be a complete copy, consider mounting in a way that gives you the full picture.

Comment: You could ask the same about many flags, eg `-i`: "why not just specify a destination that doesn't exist"?

Comment: @JigglyNaga I was thinking that as well. But -x was not phrased well in the documentation and far less obvious.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

It limits where files are copied *from*, not where they’re copied to. It’s useful with recursive copies, to control how `cp` descends into subdirectories. Thus

```
cp -xr / blah
```

will only copy the root file system, not any of the other file systems mounted.

See [the `cp -x` documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/cp-invocation.html#index-file-systems_002c-omitting-copying-to-different) (although its distinction is subtle).

Comment: Oh yes, you might not want to copy network shares under /mnt.  Nor a remote RCS repository mounted under your home drive.

Comment: @mckenzm Also because `/mnt` is only a human convention sometimes enforced by a distro's setup but not a requirement of the OS. I sometimes have network filesystems mounted under `/var/somewebsite/www/sessions` to implement load balancing web servers

Comment: Indeed, this kind of flag prevents accidentally copying huge network shares or removable media that you forgot you had mounted. And you don't need to give `--exclude` options to manually block each of them. Very useful with rsync.

Comment: It also avoids copying file systems such as `/dev`, `/proc`, `/sys` etc. which you typically don’t want to read “en masse”.

Answer (score 29):

The `-x` flag to `cp` is a GNU extension. When copying a single file, this option will have no effect, but when copying a whole file hierarchy, the `-x` option prevents the copying of files and directories that do not live on the same filesystem as the original source.

For example, on a filesystem with mount points at `/usr` and `/usr/local`, using `cp -xR /usr /some-dest` would not copy the hierarchy under `/usr/local`.

There are other utilities with an `-x` option with similar semantics, such as `du` and `find` (the flag is called `-xdev` for `find`), and `rsync`.