# 100% disk usage for a file system

Tags: centos

I see that `df` reports a 100% disk usage for a file system. How can I see which folder is eating the disk space?

```
[root@rocks7 mahmood]# df -h
Filesystem                     Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/rocks_rocks7-root   50G   48G     0 100% /
devtmpfs                        32G     0   32G   0% /dev
tmpfs                           32G     0   32G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs                           32G  9.3M   32G   1% /run
tmpfs                           32G     0   32G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs                           16G   32M   16G   1% /var/lib/ganglia/rrds
/dev/sda1                      976M  709M  201M  78% /boot
tmpfs                          6.3G   12K  6.3G   1% /run/user/42
tmpfs                          6.3G     0  6.3G   0% /run/user/1000
```

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/358331/30851

Comment: On a sidenote, you have too many / too large instances of tmpfs. Consider using sane size limits for them.

Comment: @frostschutz It can be swapped out, so I think it is not so bad. I suspect, his distro had it set up on this way.

Answer (score 0):

`du` is a command line tool, should be installed. Then there is `baobab` (part of gnome), and `k4dirstat` (part of kde). You wont be able to install anything until you get some space (unless you do something like mount an overlay ram disk, but that is another question).

If the problem is not in `/home`, then you will need to look at tools that are part of the installer, to figure out what programs are using the space (but I suspect the problem is in your files, not the OS).

Comment: Should be able to install - most of the 5% reserved is still available for root.

Answer (score 0):

Another very neat tool for analysing for disc usage is `ncdu` - it works on the command line, shows the major consumers of space and provides a simple way to cleanup stuff as you go. Highly recommended.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to see which file/folder is eating space, in your case that is /, you could do `ls -AlhRS / | less`.