# Centos mysterious disk space use df vs du

Tags: linux, disk-usage, xfs

My root disk is showing 100% filled space, but checking space used via `du` it is far less. I tried to zero "deleted" files but still the space is not recovered. It is an xfs file system, but since it is active root, I am unable to run xfs_repair either assuming xfs corruption is the cause.

```
[root@localhost]# df -h
Filesystem               Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/centos-root  140G  140G  480M 100% /
devtmpfs                 4.8G     0  4.8G   0% /dev
tmpfs                    4.9G   96K  4.9G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs                    4.9G  8.8M  4.8G   1% /run
tmpfs                    4.9G     0  4.9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda1                497M  212M  285M  43% /boot
/dev/mapper/centos-home   26G   14G   13G  53% /home
tmpfs                    984M   16K  984M   1% /run/user/1001
tmpfs                    984M     0  984M   0% /run/user/1005

[root@localhost]# df -i
Filesystem                Inodes  IUsed    IFree IUse% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/centos-root  2773376 359289  2414087   13% /
devtmpfs                 1255381    412  1254969    1% /dev
tmpfs                    1259308      9  1259299    1% /dev/shm
tmpfs                    1259308    533  1258775    1% /run
tmpfs                    1259308     16  1259292    1% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda1                 512000    337   511663    1% /boot
/dev/mapper/centos-home 26812416 228557 26583859    1% /home
tmpfs                    1259308     29  1259279    1% /run/user/1001
tmpfs                    1259308      1  1259307    1% /run/user/1005

[root@localhost]# du -cha --max-depth=1 /* 2>/dev/null | grep -E "G"
6.8G    /home/mdgdev
6.5G    /home/joc
14G /home
7.8G    /opt/tools
2.9G    /opt/servers
1.9G    /opt/ide
15G /opt
2.3G    /usr/lib64
2.1G    /usr/share
6.0G    /usr
1.5G    /var
37G total

[root@localhost]# du -cha --max-depth=1 --one-file-system /
55M /etc
6.2M    /root
3.8M    /tmp
1.5G    /var
6.0G    /usr
0   /bin
0   /sbin
0   /lib
0   /lib64
527M    /media
0   /mnt
15G /opt
0   /srv
0   /1
23G /
23G total


[root@localhost]# fdisk -l

Disk /dev/sda: 85.9 GB, 85899345920 bytes, 167772160 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk label type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x000915f2

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *        2048     1026047      512000   83  Linux
/dev/sda2         1026048   167772159    83373056   8e  Linux LVM

Disk /dev/sdb: 96.6 GB, 96636764160 bytes, 188743680 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk label type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x6db5b417

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdb1            2048   188743679    94370816   8e  Linux LVM

Disk /dev/mapper/centos-root: 150.3 GB, 150319661056 bytes, 293593088 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/mapper/centos-swap: 4160 MB, 4160749568 bytes, 8126464 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/mapper/centos-home: 27.5 GB, 27455913984 bytes, 53624832 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

[root@localhost]# lsof +L1
lsof: WARNING: can't stat() fuse.gvfsd-fuse file system /run/user/1001/gvfs
      Output information may be incomplete.
COMMAND    PID   USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NLINK     NODE NAME
firewalld  867   root    6u   REG  253,0     4096     0   155896 /tmp/ffind58tf (deleted)
tuned     1250   root    7u   REG  253,0     4096     0   473890 /tmp/ffiq5HmVK (deleted)
gnome-she 4403 mdgdev   17u   REG  253,0    12288     0   473892 /tmp/ffigM0yja (deleted)
nautilus  4849 mdgdev   19r   REG  253,2        1     0 39275271 /home/mdgdev/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/home.4IMV3Z (deleted)
nautilus  4849 mdgdev   20r   REG  253,2        1     0 39918423 /home/mdgdev/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/home-ba8e73ee.log (deleted)
java      5297 mdgdev  411u   REG  253,0     4096     0   473903 /tmp/ffiuQh5F3 (deleted)
java      5492 mdgdev   79u   REG  253,0     4096     0   473905 /tmp/ffikyoITY (deleted)


[root@localhost]# mount | column -t
sysfs                    on  /sys                             type  sysfs            (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,seclabel)
proc                     on  /proc                            type  proc             (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
devtmpfs                 on  /dev                             type  devtmpfs         (rw,nosuid,seclabel,size=5021524k,nr_inodes=1255381,mode=755)
securityfs               on  /sys/kernel/security             type  securityfs       (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
tmpfs                    on  /dev/shm                         type  tmpfs            (rw,nosuid,nodev,seclabel)
devpts                   on  /dev/pts                         type  devpts           (rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,seclabel,gid=5,mode=620,ptmxmode=000)
tmpfs                    on  /run                             type  tmpfs            (rw,nosuid,nodev,seclabel,mode=755)
tmpfs                    on  /sys/fs/cgroup                   type  tmpfs            (ro,nosuid,nodev,noexec,seclabel,mode=755)
cgroup                   on  /sys/fs/cgroup/systemd           type  cgroup           (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,xattr,release_agent=/usr/lib/systemd/systemd-cgroups-agent,name=systemd)
pstore                   on  /sys/fs/pstore                   type  pstore           (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
cgroup                   on  /sys/fs/cgroup/perf_event        type  cgroup           (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,perf_event)
cgroup                   on  /sys/fs/cgroup/memory            type  cgroup           (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,memory)
cgroup                   on  /sys/fs/cgroup/cpu,cpuacct       type  cgroup           (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,cpuacct,cpu)
cgroup                   on  /sys/fs/cgroup/freezer           type  cgroup           (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,freezer)
cgroup                   on  /sys/fs/cgroup/cpuset            type  cgroup           (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,cpuset)
cgroup                   on  /sys/fs/cgroup/net_cls,net_prio  type  cgroup           (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,net_prio,net_cls)
cgroup                   on  /sys/fs/cgroup/pids              type  cgroup           (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,pids)
cgroup                   on  /sys/fs/cgroup/devices           type  cgroup           (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,devices)
cgroup                   on  /sys/fs/cgroup/blkio             type  cgroup           (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,blkio)
cgroup                   on  /sys/fs/cgroup/hugetlb           type  cgroup           (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,hugetlb)
configfs                 on  /sys/kernel/config               type  configfs         (rw,relatime)
/dev/mapper/centos-root  on  /                                type  xfs              (rw,relatime,seclabel,attr2,inode64,noquota)
selinuxfs                on  /sys/fs/selinux                  type  selinuxfs        (rw,relatime)
systemd-1                on  /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc         type  autofs           (rw,relatime,fd=33,pgrp=1,timeout=300,minproto=5,maxproto=5,direct)
debugfs                  on  /sys/kernel/debug                type  debugfs          (rw,relatime)
mqueue                   on  /dev/mqueue                      type  mqueue           (rw,relatime,seclabel)
hugetlbfs                on  /dev/hugepages                   type  hugetlbfs        (rw,relatime,seclabel)
nfsd                     on  /proc/fs/nfsd                    type  nfsd             (rw,relatime)
/dev/sda1                on  /boot                            type  xfs              (rw,relatime,seclabel,attr2,inode64,noquota)
/dev/mapper/centos-home  on  /home                            type  xfs              (rw,relatime,seclabel,attr2,inode64,noquota)
sunrpc                   on  /var/lib/nfs/rpc_pipefs          type  rpc_pipefs       (rw,relatime)
tmpfs                    on  /run/user/1001                   type  tmpfs            (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,seclabel,size=1007448k,mode=700,uid=1001,gid=1001)
fusectl                  on  /sys/fs/fuse/connections         type  fusectl          (rw,relatime)
gvfsd-fuse               on  /run/user/1001/gvfs              type  fuse.gvfsd-fuse  (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=1001,group_id=1001)
binfmt_misc              on  /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc         type  binfmt_misc      (rw,relatime)
tmpfs                    on  /run/user/1005                   type  tmpfs            (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,seclabel,size=1007448k,mode=700,uid=1005,gid=1006)

[root@localhost]# mount | column -t | grep xfs
/dev/mapper/centos-root  on  /                                type  xfs              (rw,relatime,seclabel,attr2,inode64,noquota)
selinuxfs                on  /sys/fs/selinux                  type  selinuxfs        (rw,relatime)
/dev/sda1                on  /boot                            type  xfs              (rw,relatime,seclabel,attr2,inode64,noquota)
/dev/mapper/centos-home  on  /home                            type  xfs              (rw,relatime,seclabel,attr2,inode64,noquota)
```

Can anyone advice how could I recover this disk space please?

Comment: How did you run `du`? It will only count files that it can see.

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/358331/30851

Comment: please show output of `du -cha --max-depth=1 --one-file-system /` Note no `*` and `--one-file-system`.

Comment: I added the output for "du -cha --max-depth=1 --one-file-system /" to the main comment.