# XFS mount at 100% full, how to pinpoint problem

Tags: xfs

running SLES 11.4 on a server, there are ~5 disks as Raid-5 via LSI megaraid, which provides 2.2 TB of usable space...  when creating this it showed up as `/dev/sdb` and I created one parition as XFS, mounted it as `/data` and that showed up as 0% use with 2.2TB of space available.  A `df -h` still shows the mount as 2.2T available, but at 100% full.

If I do, as root, `du -sh /data/*` I get a listing which adds up to less than 100GB.  What options do I have to rectify this?  What might cause something like this?

Comment: maybe related https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/358331/30851 - that and `*` might not include .hidden files

Comment: posting literal commands & output instead of renarrating what output you saw might also help

Answer (score 0):

**reboot fixed the problem**, one user was doing a lot of parallel I/O which in the past has caused problems.  my XFS mount came back @ 85GB used 2.1T free.  After reboot, also did `umount /dev/sdb1; xfs_repair -n /dev/sdb1` and that reported no problems.  I could not do *xfs_repair* before the reboot even got an *XFS library initialization error* so something was messed up after 40 days of uptime.

- There were no hidden files under `/data/`
- `/dev/sdb1` was mounted as `/data`
- there is simply `/data/ron` and `/data/john` and `/data/misc`; doing a `du -sh /data/*` showed values adding up to only ~85GB for each of the ~8 folders under `/data`.  Nothing more to explain, don't know what else to do with XFS other than ***reboot*** and ***xfs_repair -n***.

any insight or advice i guess leave as a comment

not the first time I've had this happen with XFS