# The filesystem is already 65010688 (4k) blocks long

Tags: partition, lvm, size, resize2fs

Please help me , when I try to increase the partition size in LVM, but when I try it doesn’t work,
I do the following:

```
  df -h


Filesystem                         Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev                               3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /dev
tmpfs                              795M  1.3M  794M   1% /run
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv  244G  113G  121G  49% /


sudo lvextend --resizefs -l +100%FREE ubuntu-vg/ubuntu-lv

  Size of logical volume ubuntu-vg/ubuntu-lv unchanged from <248.00 GiB (63487 extents).
  Logical volume ubuntu-vg/ubuntu-lv successfully resized.
resize2fs 1.45.5 (07-Jan-2020)
The filesystem is already 65010688 (4k) blocks long.  Nothing to do!

df -h

 Filesystem                         Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv  244G  113G  121G  49% /

sudo vgs
  VG        #PV #LV #SN Attr   VSize    VFree
  ubuntu-vg   1   1   0 wz--n- <248.00g    0

lsblk

NAME                      MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
loop0                       7:0    0 63.5M  1 loop /snap/core20/1974
loop1                       7:1    0 63.5M  1 loop /snap/core20/2015
loop2                       7:2    0 91.9M  1 loop /snap/lxd/24061
loop3                       7:3    0 40.9M  1 loop /snap/snapd/20290
loop4                       7:4    0 40.9M  1 loop /snap/snapd/20092
sda                         8:0    0  250G  0 disk
├─sda1                      8:1    0    1M  0 part
├─sda2                      8:2    0    2G  0 part /boot
└─sda3                      8:3    0  248G  0 part
  └─ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv 253:0    0  248G  0 lvm  /
sr0                        11:0    1 1024M  0 rom

sudo vgdisplay
  --- Volume group ---
  VG Name               ubuntu-vg
  System ID
  Format                lvm2
  Metadata Areas        1
  Metadata Sequence No  5
  VG Access             read/write
  VG Status             resizable
  MAX LV                0
  Cur LV                1
  Open LV               1
  Max PV                0
  Cur PV                1
  Act PV                1
  VG Size               <248.00 GiB
  PE Size               4.00 MiB
  Total PE              63487
  Alloc PE / Size       63487 / <248.00 GiB
  Free  PE / Size       0 / 0
  VG UUID               Vl06pF-MGCJ-WFC9-Vz45-UCuf-EsEI-9IFP8R
```

Afterwards everything remains the same. I don't understand what I'm doing wrong. More precisely, I do not have a complete understanding.

Comment: How much free space is there in the volume group? What does `sudo vgs` output?

Comment: Stephane,hello

  VG        #PV #LV #SN Attr   VSize    VFree


  ubuntu-vg   1   1   0 wz--n- <248.00g    0

Comment: Please add that information to the question, not comments. You may also want to add the output of `lsblk`.

Answer (score 1):

The LV is already at its maximum size of approximately 247 GiB and there are no more extents available to allocate:

> ```
> vgdisplay
> --- Volume group ---
> VG Name               ubuntu-vg
> ...
> VG Size               <248.00 GiB
> PE Size               4.00 MiB
> Total PE              63487
> Alloc PE / Size       63487 / <248.00 GiB
> Free  PE / Size       0 / 0
> ```

There is a little over half of the filesystem it contains still unused:

> ```
> df -h
> Filesystem                         Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
> /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv  244G  113G  121G  49% /
> ```

Comment: I understand this, but I can’t expand the partition to the maximum possible capacity.

Comment: You've already done so

Comment: Ok.why available space only 121G?

Comment: @ГлебЩеголев check root reserve (`tune2fs -l` for ext4), and/or [ncdu](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/358331/30851)

Answer (score 0):

What a fool I am. For some reason I thought that this was all available, and not how much was left. Such thoughts arose due to an error that there is not enough disk space. But actually everything is fine. Sorry for the nonsense(