# Can’t boot laptop (Linux Mint)

Tags: linux, linux-mint, cinnamon

I was watching YouTube with Tor Browser, when the storage on my computer got full. This happened yesterday and the storage got emptied again after a while. The program that shows what files use up storage showed that /var and timeshift had used up the most. When the storage got full again today, I ignored it, since it had just gone down again the other day.

This time YouTube started crashing first, then programs wouldn’t open. I couldn’t even turn the computer off on the GUI, so I pressed the power switch on my laptop.

I went into recovery mode and under system summary it says /dev/mapper/mint--vg-root is using 214GB, 100% use. I pressed resume and was able to open it up for a short while. Under program files it says 0 bytes free space.

Does anyone know what all that used up storage is? What can I do to reset my laptop? I don’t have any important files and I had barely even downloaded software so I don’t mind if it all gets deleted.

Currently back in recovery menu.

Details:
Asus X541U Laptop
Linux Mint 19.1 Cinnamon, with Linux 4.15.0-52-generic (recovery mode)

Edit: I deleted a few files with the root shell prompt. Then I was able to start mint normally. Checking the free space it had a bit more than 1GB. It started going down again without me doing anything. I thought maybe it’s downloading something so I turned off the wifi but it kept going until things stopped working again.

Edit2: I deleted a timeshift snapshots depository and it freed up about 70GB. Should I just remove timeshift? Because it copying files made me unable to use anything. Also I have no idea why snapshots are so big when I have almost nothing downloaded. Otherwise, I’m able to use my laptop now again.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Disk usage on a specific filesystem](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/358319/disk-usage-on-a-specific-filesystem)

Answer (score 2):

The lesson you learned here is to keep your root separate from your `/home`.

Also, do you mean you are backing up your system in the same drive? Don't do that. Use a separate disk/partition for backup.

If, as you said, don't mind reinstall your system, keep those things in mind.

Comment: By keeping root separate from /home do you mean I should give them separate names? Sorry if that’s a dumb question.

Comment: @ninjaone They mean `/home` should be a separate partition.  That way, if it fills up, the root file system will not be affected.  It's also common to keep `/var` on its own partition for the same reason.  I would also suggest doing backups to a drive external to your main computer, like a NAS or some other account on another machine, or just an external hard drive (I'm assuming timeshift is some sort of backup software, that's why I mention it).  Keeping backups on the same disk as you back up is pretty useless if the disk crashes.

Comment: @Kusalananda how do I do that?

Comment: @ninjaone I'm not sure which part of my comment you are referring to. Do a search on this site for similar questions, and if you can't find anything of interest, ask a new question.

Comment: @Kusalananda sorry I only saw the first part of your comment not sure if you edited it or it’s something on my part. Thanks for the info.

Comment: Backup to a separate drive, nay, a drive in a separate PC, in infinitely preferable and makes the backup much more likely to be there when you need it. Always verify that backup, too, for an unverified backup is a waste of time and space.

Comment: @K7AAY: thank for pointing out. In my mind, I was thinking of external disk. Backing up on same pc is inviting the disaster.